# If not visible, fix a grid-item on Masonry (top-right)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, masonry

Im trying to get a grid-item of masonry fixed on the top right of grid container. If I scroll the window, and the item is no more visible, it gets fixed on the top right. 
Im trying to apply this CSS to the third grid-item:

```
.fixed-top-right{
position: fixed;
top:0;
right:0;
}
```

This is my html:

```
<div class="grid">
    <div class="grid-sizer"></div>
    <div class="grid-item">
        <img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/82/submerged.jpg" />
    </div>
    <div class="grid-item">
        <img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/82/submerged.jpg" />
    </div>
    <div class="grid-item fixed-top-right">
        <img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri().'/img/submergedbp.jpg'; ?>" />
    </div>
    <div class="grid-item">
        <img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/82/submerged.jpg" />
    </div>
    <div class="grid-item">
        <img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/82/submerged.jpg" />
    </div>
    <div class="grid-item">
        <img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/82/submerged.jpg" />
    </div>
    <div class="grid-item">
        <img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/82/submerged.jpg" />
    </div>
    <div class="grid-item">
        <img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/82/submerged.jpg" />
    </div>
    <div class="grid-item">
        <img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/82/submerged.jpg" />
    </div>
    <div class="grid-item">
        <img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/82/submerged.jpg" />
    </div>
    <div class="grid-item">
        <img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/82/submerged.jpg" />
    </div>
    <div class="grid-item">
        <img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/82/submerged.jpg" />
    </div>
    <div class="grid-item">
        <img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/82/submerged.jpg" />
</div>
```

The CSS:

```
* { box-sizing: border-box; }

/* force scrollbar */
html { overflow-y: scroll; }

/* ---- grid ---- */

.grid {
    background: #DDD;
}

/* clear fix */
.grid:after {
    content: '';
    display: block;
    clear: both;
}

/* ---- .grid-item ---- */

.grid-sizer,
.grid-item {
    width: 32.683%;
}

.grid-item {
    float: left;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.grid-item img {
    display: block;
    max-width: 100%;
}
```

And the call of masonry:

```
var $grid = $('.grid').masonry({
    itemSelector: '.grid-item',
    percentPosition: true,
    gutter: 10,
    columnWidth: '.grid-sizer'
});
// layout Masonry after each image loads
$grid.imagesLoaded().progress( function() {
    $grid.masonry();
});
```

[This](https://codepen.io/desandro/pen/RPKgEN) is the base code from Masonry page that I'm editing.

If I just apply my CSS, the element goes left and it doesnt stay on the top. Is there a way to make the position of a grid-item fixed top-right inside the grid container if the element is no more visible on the screen?

Comment: You can use flex table link this (https://codepen.io/nordstromdesign/pen/pbdwJv)[https://codepen.io/nordstromdesign/pen/pbdwJv] or use DataTable plugin (https://datatables.net/extensions/responsive/examples/)[https://datatables.net/extensions/responsive/examples/]

Comment: Thanks, but I need a masonry layout for my homepage.